# Cannot test JPA + Spring

Tags: java, spring, jpa, transactions

I have the following test case:

```
@ContextConfiguration("/spring/test-context.xml")
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="txManager")
@Transactional()
public class MyEntityDaoTestCase extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests { 

    @Autowired
    private MyEntityDao dao;

    @Test
    public void testSave_success() {
        MyEntity e = new MyEntity();
        dao.save(e);
        MyEntity result = dao.findById(e.getId());
        assertNotNull(result);      
    }
}
```

My DAO definition has as follows:

```
public abstract class MyEntityDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager mEntityManager;

    public void save(MyEntity entity) {
        mEntityManager.persist(entity);
    }

    public MyEntity findById(Long id) {
        return mEntityManager.find(mEntityClass, id);
    }
}
```

My Spring config is the following:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- 
        Bean post-processor for JPA annotations 
    -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

    <!--
        JPA entity manager factory 
     -->
    <bean id="jpaEntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
      <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="unit-test-pu"/>
    </bean>

    <!--
        Transaction manager 
     -->
    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="jpaEntityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- 
        Enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations 
    -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>

    <!--
        DAO instance beans 
     -->
    <bean id="mockEntityDao" class="mypackage.MyEntityDao"></bean>

</beans>
```

I get no errors while executing my test but it won't pass. It looks like the findById() method will not find the entity in the database. Can anyone advise on how to correctly test this case?

EDIT:

My JPA provider is hibernate. I am using an in-memory HSQLDB for my unit tests and have the following configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
   <persistence-unit name="unit-test-pu" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">   
      <properties>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:."/>
         <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
         <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
         <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
      </properties>      
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: What is the JPA provider and config?

Comment: I am using hibernate. I have added my configuration on my post.

Comment: MyEntity is be persisted correctly, so the id is not null for e.getId()?

Comment: MyEntity's id is null. However there are no exceptions in the console.

Comment: Try running the test without the Transaction annotations, if id is still null, there is an issue with persisting MyEntity and not with transactions.

Comment: Tried it. It's still null. I don't seem to notice any problems on the console. Anyway, i'm moments away from rejecting spring once and for all.. i'm over this bs half day and still haven't figured what's going on. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9683/discussion-between-mguymon-and-lefty)

Comment: FYI: The problem was that no transaction was initiated by spring. I solved this by including @TestExecutionListeners({TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class}) to evaluate the @Transactional annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow TDD strictly you should not use an in memory database but instead have everything mocked. The problem is that the persist method returns void. So you can not test the correct response (an entity with an id generated by a database) One way to work around this is to us the Mockito doAnswer method, here an example:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CookieRepositoryTest {

@Mock
 EntityManager em;

@Mock
 TimeService timeService;

@InjectMocks
 CookieRepository underTest = new CookieRepository();

@Test
 public void testCreateEntity() throws Exception {
 Cookie newCookie = new Cookie();

when(timeService.getTime()).thenReturn(new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC));

doAnswer(new Answer<Brand>() {
 @Override
 public Brand answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {
 Object[] args = invocationOnMock.getArguments();
 Cookie cookie = (Cookie) args[0];
 cookie.setId(1);
 return null;
 }

}).when(em).persist(any(Brand.class));

Cookie persistedCookie = underTest.createEntity(newCookie);
 assertNotNull(persistedCookie.getId());
 }

}
```

A complete explanation can be found on my blog [post](http://cyberroadie.wordpress.com/2012/07/02/how-to-test-a-jpa-repository/).

Answer (score 2):

You could try using @TransactionalConfiguration annotation and the Spring JUnit runner.

Something like changing your class to this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/spring/test-context.xml")
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="txManager", defaultRollback=true)
@Transactional
public class MyEntityDaoTestCase {
```

This also means you don't need to extend the abstract case (because you are using the Spring runner) - unless you particularly like that approach.

Here more [details](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-tx)

Comment: I have tried setting defaultRollback = true. It doesn't work.

Comment: Just a comment: Please don't use defaultRollback set to true! Hibernate keeps the insert/update statements in memory until they're flushed to the DB (by a select or explicit flush). So Hibernate might never touch the DB in your test, which means that you can still get errors when you deploy the application *although you had a test*.

Comment: And that's my problem exactly. I' WANT hibernate to flush in order to test my case. Take a look on my test method and you'll get what i mean...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be extending [AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests.html) instead of AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests for the `@Transactional`-annotations to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test the persistence layer, you could also take a look at DBUnit capabilities.

You can find a nice article from Petri Kainulainen here about testing the persistence layer (in this case with JPA) in a Spring based scenario:

http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-integration-testing/

With this, you test if the DAO classes behave as expected, writing and reading into/from the DB, and on the service layer you can avoid testing this aspect, focusing more on the "mock" approach for the business logic.

Hope it helps

Fran